# VBA Excel - Change color of every first value of a row in a determined range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to come up with something to let VBA change the color of every first entry in a row in a determined range. Basically, it should go through the different rows and everytime it does find a first entry change the color of it. If it doesn't find any entry it should just go on to the next row.

To visualise:

This is how it currently looks
[image: this is what it currently looks like]

And this is how I want it to look after the VBA code has done it's work.
[image: this is how I want it to look]

How would that work? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: loop each column and if there is a value, change the color of the cell.

Comment: This can be done with Condtional Formatting using the following formula: `=COUNTIF($C1,C1,"<>")=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the numbers starting from column C,

```
Sub highlight()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To 256
    If Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
        Cells(j, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

If not adjust the formula accordingly